# Ajax call not accepting Names with apostrophe as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".loadingPnl").removeClass('hdn');

var siteurlA = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
var callUrl = siteurlA + "/_layouts/15/SynchronyFinancial.Intranet/CreateMySite.aspx/SaveAvailableFavoriteItem";

var linkName = $('.txtLinkName').val();
linkName = linkName.replace("'","\'");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: callUrl,
    data: "{'linkName': '" + linkName + "', 'webSiteUrl':'" +  $('.txtWebAddress').val() + "','iconId':'" + $(".ddlIcons").val() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        return true;
    },
    error: function (response) {
        return true;
    }
});

return true;

}
```

Comment: Your `data:` string is not valid JSON. It's easier to just pass an object and let jQuery serialise it for you. Secondly I would remove `processData: false` - its only really used when sending binary data in AJAX. Also, your use of return statements in the `success` and `error` functions is redundant.

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to describe the issue. It would be nice if you pointed to where in the code your issue is .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're building JSON yourself as the request parameters. Moreover, you're building [*invalid* JSON](http://json.org/) (JSON property names are *always* with double quotes (`"`)).

Instead, pass an object and let jQuery take care of how to send it - if you pass that instead of a string the server can figure it out. If you *really* want to do it yourself you can also pass an object to `JSON.stringify`.

```
var payload = {
    linkName: linkName,
    webSiteUrl: $('.txtWebAddress').val(),
    iconId: $(".ddlIcons").val()
};



 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: callUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(payload), // or just payload
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false, // if you just pass payload, remove this
    dataType: "json" 
    // you had two `return`s here, but they wouldn't work, make sure
    // you understand why
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a JSON instead. Or use **JSON.stringify** if you want String.

```
{
    'linkName' : linkName,
    'webSiteUrl' : $('.txtWebAddress').val(),
    'iconId' :  $(".ddlIcons").val()
}
```

Comment: JavaScript objects are not JSON, and jQuery will serialise them using form data encoding, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't create JSON string by yourself AND don't use JSON.stringify().**

Problem with creating JSON string yourself is to escape string properly for JavaScript (which could be tricky). [see Special Characters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Problem with JSON.stringify is that I found it somehow slower than XMLHttpRequest which is strange because I thought it is using JSON.stringify behind curtains.

XMLHttpRequest is handling this for you. If you just pass your object as a data and XMLHttRequest will do the trick.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: callUrl,
   data: {'linkName': linkName, 
          'webSiteUrl': $('.txtWebAddress').val(),
          'iconId': $(".ddlIcons").val()
         },
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   processData: false,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (response) {
       return true;
   },
   error: function (response) {
       return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest (assuming you mean XHR2 with `.send(data)` doesn't use JSON.stringify behind the scenes - in fact I'm not sure you can send JSON data with xhr (you can send form data).